# Android emulator 4.0.3 Crashed when input text in a website through Webview

Tags: android, webview, emulation

I've made a simple Android app that's trying to open a URL (any URL with input will do) on a click of a button.
The code I use is this :

```
btnTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HelloActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
        }
    });
```

The problem is that in Android Emulator running Platform 4.0.3, the emulator is crashed everytime I try to input text using soft keyboard into the web. This problem doesn't occur in Emulator running Platform 2.3.3. I've tried many sites and it behaves the same.

Btw, this is the logcat :

```
02-22 09:35:51.434: I/ActivityManager(81): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.eatmicco.Training/.HelloActivity} from pid 212
02-22 09:35:51.444: D/PermissionCache(36): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1000 => granted (623 us)
02-22 09:35:51.704: D/dalvikvm(81): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 149K, 7% free 11999K/12871K, paused 79ms
02-22 09:35:51.714: I/dalvikvm-heap(81): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.914MB for 129616-byte allocation
02-22 09:35:51.844: D/dalvikvm(81): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 745K, 13% free 11380K/12999K, paused 68ms
02-22 09:35:51.913: D/dalvikvm(478): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-22 09:35:51.944: I/ActivityManager(81): Start proc com.eatmicco.Training for activity com.eatmicco.Training/.HelloActivity: pid=478 uid=10048 gids={1015}
02-22 09:35:51.954: D/(81): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xbdd28, tid 123
02-22 09:35:52.094: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(81): setKernelCountSet(10048, 1) failed with errno -2
02-22 09:35:52.124: D/OpenGLRenderer(212): Flushing caches (mode 1)
02-22 09:35:52.334: V/PhoneStatusBar(151): setLightsOn(true)
02-22 09:35:52.533: W/InputManagerService(81): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415554e8 (uid=10013 pid=212)
02-22 09:35:52.533: D/(478): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x15c708, tid 478
02-22 09:35:52.593: D/OpenGLRenderer(212): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-22 09:35:52.704: I/Process(81): Sending signal. PID: 478 SIG: 3
02-22 09:35:52.704: I/dalvikvm(478): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-22 09:35:52.714: I/dalvikvm(478): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-22 09:35:53.004: I/ActivityManager(81): Displayed com.eatmicco.Training/.HelloActivity: +1s114ms
02-22 09:35:53.154: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(81): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2
02-22 09:35:54.204: I/ActivityManager(81): START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity} from pid 478
02-22 09:35:54.573: I/ActivityManager(81): Start proc com.android.browser for activity com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity: pid=491 uid=10002 gids={3003, 1015}
02-22 09:35:54.673: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(81): setKernelCountSet(10002, 1) failed with errno -2
02-22 09:35:54.933: I/ActivityThread(491): Pub com.android.browser;browser: com.android.browser.provider.BrowserProvider2
02-22 09:35:54.984: I/ActivityThread(491): Pub com.android.browser.home: com.android.browser.homepages.HomeProvider
02-22 09:35:54.984: I/ActivityThread(491): Pub com.android.browser.snapshots: com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider
02-22 09:35:55.193: I/Process(81): Sending signal. PID: 491 SIG: 3
02-22 09:35:55.193: I/dalvikvm(491): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-22 09:35:55.303: I/dalvikvm(491): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-22 09:35:55.553: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_CONCURRENT freed 257K, 4% free 9281K/9607K, paused 8ms+4ms
02-22 09:35:55.603: E/ActivityThread(491): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
02-22 09:35:55.603: E/ActivityThread(491): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
02-22 09:35:55.693: I/Process(81): Sending signal. PID: 491 SIG: 3
02-22 09:35:55.693: I/dalvikvm(491): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-22 09:35:55.813: I/dalvikvm(491): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-22 09:35:55.893: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 191K, 4% free 9475K/9799K, paused 34ms
02-22 09:35:55.943: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 4% free 9647K/9991K, paused 31ms
02-22 09:35:55.993: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 9818K/10183K, paused 42ms
02-22 09:35:56.023: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 9989K/10375K, paused 35ms
02-22 09:35:56.073: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 10162K/10567K, paused 32ms
02-22 09:35:56.114: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 10504K/10759K, paused 33ms
02-22 09:35:56.163: E/libEGL(491): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-22 09:35:56.183: D/ShaderProgram(491): couldn't load the vertex shader!
02-22 09:35:56.183: E/libEGL(491): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-22 09:35:56.183: D/ShaderProgram(491): couldn't load the vertex shader!
02-22 09:35:56.183: E/libEGL(491): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-22 09:35:56.183: D/ShaderProgram(491): couldn't load the vertex shader!
02-22 09:35:56.183: E/libEGL(491): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-22 09:35:56.183: D/ShaderProgram(491): couldn't load the vertex shader!
02-22 09:35:56.183: E/libEGL(491): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-22 09:35:56.183: D/ShaderProgram(491): couldn't load the vertex shader!
02-22 09:35:56.193: I/Process(81): Sending signal. PID: 491 SIG: 3
02-22 09:35:56.193: I/dalvikvm(491): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-22 09:35:56.233: I/dalvikvm(491): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-22 09:35:56.383: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 3% free 10896K/11143K, paused 57ms
02-22 09:35:56.393: D/WebViewTimersControl(491): onBrowserActivityResume
02-22 09:35:56.393: D/WebViewTimersControl(491): Resuming webview timers, view=com.android.browser.BrowserWebView@41313558
02-22 09:35:56.403: W/BaseUi(491): mMainView is already attached to wrapper in attachTabToContentView!
02-22 09:35:56.413: W/BaseUi(491): mContainer is already attached to content in attachTabToContentView!
02-22 09:35:56.433: V/NFC(491): this device does not have NFC support
02-22 09:35:56.543: D/libEGL(491): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-22 09:35:56.593: D/libEGL(491): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
02-22 09:35:56.593: D/(491): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x1ec618, tid 491
02-22 09:35:56.643: D/libEGL(491): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
02-22 09:35:56.643: D/libEGL(491): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
02-22 09:35:56.703: I/Process(81): Sending signal. PID: 491 SIG: 3
02-22 09:35:56.703: I/dalvikvm(491): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-22 09:35:56.793: W/EGL_emulation(491): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-22 09:35:56.823: D/OpenGLRenderer(491): Enabling debug mode 0
02-22 09:35:56.823: I/dalvikvm(491): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-22 09:35:57.214: I/Process(81): Sending signal. PID: 491 SIG: 3
02-22 09:35:57.214: I/dalvikvm(491): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-22 09:35:57.273: I/dalvikvm(491): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-22 09:35:57.313: I/ActivityManager(81): Displayed com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity: +2s785ms
02-22 09:35:57.733: E/chromium(491): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1107: [0222/093557:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(1107)] Critical error found -8
02-22 09:35:57.893: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_CONCURRENT freed 65K, 3% free 11348K/11591K, paused 3ms+21ms
02-22 09:35:57.963: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 3% free 11337K/11591K, paused 60ms
02-22 09:35:57.963: I/dalvikvm-heap(491): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.765MB for 656656-byte allocation
02-22 09:35:57.993: W/chromium(491): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [0222/093558:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
02-22 09:35:57.993: W/chromium(491): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [0222/093558:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
02-22 09:35:58.003: W/chromium(491): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [0222/093558:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
02-22 09:35:58.033: W/chromium(491): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [0222/093558:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
02-22 09:35:58.053: E/chromium(491): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/entry_impl.cc:904: [0222/093558:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(904)] Failed to save user data
02-22 09:35:58.053: E/chromium(491): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/entry_impl.cc:904: [0222/093558:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(904)] Failed to save user data
02-22 09:35:58.143: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 11979K/12295K, paused 121ms
02-22 09:35:58.263: W/Tab(491): Failed to save back/forward list for http://www.google.com
02-22 09:35:58.883: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(81): setKernelCountSet(10048, 0) failed with errno -2
02-22 09:36:03.363: D/dalvikvm(165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 118K, 3% free 9760K/9991K, paused 4ms+5ms
02-22 09:36:04.403: D/(165): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x1e7f50, tid 165
02-22 09:36:04.773: D/dalvikvm(165): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 143K, 3% free 9844K/10119K, paused 224ms
02-22 09:36:04.803: I/dalvikvm-heap(165): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.241MB for 591376-byte allocation
02-22 09:36:04.913: D/dalvikvm(165): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 4% free 10412K/10759K, paused 99ms
02-22 09:36:05.053: D/dalvikvm(165): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 10413K/10759K, paused 3ms+4ms
02-22 09:36:05.623: D/dalvikvm(151): GC_CONCURRENT freed 174K, 29% free 9975K/13959K, paused 4ms+16ms
02-22 09:36:05.803: D/dalvikvm(81): GC_CONCURRENT freed 278K, 12% free 11569K/12999K, paused 5ms+28ms
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: please post your logcat log...

Comment: logcat added, thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: I've found the mistake. Apparently, the problem is with the configuration of my AVD that's running platform 4.0.3. After I changed the Device Ram Size from 800 to 512 and Max VM application heap from 256 to 48 the problem dissapeared.
I noticed this after I tried to open browser application in the emulator and it had the same problem.